# Reducing data consumption with Firebase Database

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, websocket

I am working on an application that sends a user's location. This project requires that the position is streamed constantly, as soon as a change is detected by the device.

This means on average our application is sending data to Firebase Database every 1.5 seconds.

This is what a typical update currently looks like:

```
firebase.database().ref('/users/user_id').update({
    latitude: 50.34132,
    longitude: -1.45345
    speed: 63,
    heading: 350
})
```

My question might seem somewhat stupid/obvious, but what I'm asking is, 
 would updating the data like this (below) make more sense in terms of conserving network data?

```
firebase.database().ref('/users/user_id').update({
    a: 50.34132,
    b: -1.45345
    c: 63,
    d: 350
})
```

Obviously by sending data this way, we need to keep a 'legend' of sorts so that we know which field is mapped to which letter, but am I correct in saying that this will save our users some network data as it's transmitting less bytes?

I believe Firebase Database sends the update request through a web socket, so if my understanding correct this could potentially save us ~30 bytes for each location update?